# Inconsistent query execution times in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have run three queries in SSMS and cannot understand the difference in time it takes each of them to run.  The first two queries extract data for a single month, the third extracts data for both  months.  All queries work correctly, but I cannot understand how the second one can take so long to run.
The queries, the number of records returned and the time taken for each query is as follows:
Can anyone explain this?

```
SELECT *
  FROM [vw_Movement]
  WHERE ShiftDateTime BETWEEN '1 Aug 14 6:00' AND '31 Aug 14 18:00'
(Rcds returned=16,342, time=0 secs)



SELECT *
  FROM [vw_Movement]
  WHERE ShiftDateTime BETWEEN '1 Sep 14 6:00' AND '30 Sep 14 18:00'
(Rcds returned=14,468, time=24 secs)



SELECT *
  FROM [vw_Movement]
  WHERE ShiftDateTime BETWEEN '1 Aug 14 6:00' AND '30 Sep 14 18:00'
(Rcds returned=30,810, time=0 secs)
```

Comment: Try restarting SQL server process and running queries again - are query times still unreasonable? If you restart-query several times, are average times still unreasonable? You may have hit cache in first and third query

Comment: Do these queries consistenty perform like this? If not, run these queries multiple times and average the results.

Comment: @SergeyVolegov: I hope it isn't a production server.

Comment: @GKB: It's not so uncommon. To understand why there this difference for execution time between these queries you should add to your question the [actual] execution plans (SSMS > Ctrl + M > F5) in XML format (use pastebin).

Comment: Looks like an outdated statistics or index fragmentation issue, but without knowing what's inside the view, it could be anything. Can you update your question with the view' definition script?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the execution plan (CTL-L in SSMS)? You don't say whether or not the underlying data is in a view or table, but from the vw_ prefix, I'm going to go with view.

So you might also want to try looking at the view definition itself, copy it as a new query into SSMS, put the WHERE statement at the end, and analyze the entire query instead of just the view. Maybe by commenting out some of the joins you can narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It likely is related to

(1) statistics - you can update the statistics of the underlying tables for thatview during your maintenance window.  People warn of running update stats during normal business hours, I feel that depends on your workload. Update stats doesn't lock the tables from my experience should be okay but it really depends on how much the db server/host can handle.

(2) Bad query plan cached in procedure cache. If you search the internet you can find methods to specifically remove on your specific cached query plan. The bad plan is also related to bad old statistics.

FYI - By updating stats you automatically your query will be recompiled due to change in stats. Taking action of (2) should not be needed.